# Would the "Rule Lawyers" pen-and-paper game be feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, law, games

> **Anri (DM)**: All right, new turn!
> **Gyvaris (in-character)**:  DM, I believe that Viri was using hearsay as evidence, which is inadmissible.
> **Viri (in-character)**: Actually, it's not hearsay if you aren't trying to use the truth of the matter asserted in the statement as
> evidence itself.
> **Anri (DM)**: Sorry, Gyv, she's right, (she opens the core rulebook) there!
> **Gyvaris**: W-what? The rule is a sentence and the rest of the page are its exceptions!
> **Viri (laughing)**: *"That's how the Maffia works"*   (The DM also chuckles a bit)
> **Viri**: Don't be so down Gyv, I also used to suck at this game, heck, I never got through the *Property Law* expansion books! But
> you'll get good eventually, besides, it's about having fun!
> **Gyvaris**: Even when you're losing?
> **Viri**: Even when you aren't losing.

Mephistopheles had a very simple plan in mind when he released the Shadow:

The creature would ravage the economy, driving up potion prices, thus causing the monster hunters to go bankrupt from the maintenance costs and forcing them to lower their members' pensions. At that point, Meph's Armored Mecha Penguinator smashing their veterans to pieces with its iron flippers was a mercy kill.

However, the Shadow didn't stop and continued to wear mankind down.

Nowadays, the process is in a frail equilibrium, the Shadow can't destroy humans, and humans can't do anything to push the Shadow further back.

One of the adaptations of society to these new conditions was moving resources out of "pointless" bureaucracies. For instance, civil cases with inconclusive evidence, as well as defamation lawsuits, are settled via trial by combat.

Let's not go into the morality of that, but the point is that there aren't any civil lawsuits nowadays that couldn't be decided by a good beatdown.

So, classical civil lawsuits make a "return" in the form of *"Rule Lawyers"*, a popular pen-and-paper game where characters assume the role of lawyers in civil lawsuits. The cases are randomly generated and the winner of a game is determined by points, so a good defense, even if ultimately failing, could still win if the prosecutor got penalties.

The basic idea is that since this world has fantasy creatures like dragons (Gyvaris, in the above example), and gryphons (Anri and Viri); the least mundane thing for them would be to play as normal humans in a normal world.

**But I'm unsure if law could be gamified.**

To be more exact, the playability of the game hinges on whether I can split the law into the following pieces:

1. **The Core Rulebook**, which is the collection of rules that will always come up for both DMs and players.
2. **Player Handbook**, which is the info for the lawyers (players). Rules for the defense and prosecution are put into different
   segments.
3. **Expansions** are just the above two but with a different "subject", like property or copyright law.

**But would it be possible to compartmentalize US law in the way I described above and would the complexity of individual pieces still be in the "playable" category by the standards of real tabletop RPGs?**

I suggest looking at D&D 3.5e, GURPS and FATAL (if you dare descend into that hole of depravity, I'M WARNING YA!)

Comment: Don't forget *Hero System* -- 5th edition core rules ran to about 800 pages, all in one volume, and with (what I considered, as a GURPS player), a grossly inadequate list of advantages, limitations, and skills.  Most of the core rules were about *how to make new rules* in the form of Power write-ups, whether those be for the original *Champions*, spells for *Fantasy Hero*, etc.  Fun game to play, but I wouldn't even try to make a character on my own, never mind GM.

Comment: I'm nost sure about U.S. law (of which I know very little), but I *am* sure that in European continental countries the law **is** written down in detail. Bonus! We don't really have a concept of "precedent", so the rule books are all that's needed. For the basic package you will easily find online copies (and, better, *annotated* copies) of the Civil Code, Commercial Code and Code of Procedure of, for example, France. Expect about a dozen hefty volumes of rules and explanations; most people who are interested in becoming lawyers spend a few years studying them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about world building.

Comment: The golden rule of thumb is yall idiots better know who is the DM, the god, the alpha and the omega, your destiny, your fate and your most trusted friend!

Comment: This belongs on Role-playing Games Stack Exchange, not here.

Comment: This isn't an answerable question. It is a question that prompts a lot of discussion and forum-style debate. As such, it really isn't appropriate for any Stack Exchange. It is a form of worldbuilding, but isn't a specific enough question. VTC.

Comment: If two lawyers meet they have three different opinions on the same thing.

Comment: Voted to Reopen. This is a very straightforward question that can easily be answered.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, +1 just for the phrase `there aren't any civil lawsuits nowadays that couldn't be decided by a good beatdown.` What can I say except, Amen!

However, games like this already exist. The first I encountered was a simple pen-and-paper version in the book *[Metamagical Themas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamagical_Themas).* If I recall correctly, you could write down any law the players came up with to proceed with the game (the "laws" applied to the game, not real life). The only rule was that you couldn't simply delete a law, you had to write law that modified previous law (as happens in contemporary legislation). The author noted that games tended to get very complicated, very quickly, and as a result tended to be very short. My experience with the game proved that to be very true.

However, the purpose of that game was to help people understand the inherent complexity with legislation. You might be trying to "gamify" the "actuality" of (for example) U.S. law. That incorporates the same process as I just mentioned, but extends it to include things like constituents wanting preferences, petitions for change, violations demonstrating weaknesses.... There are games like that out there. Here are a few I found quickly via Google (though they're not pen-and-paper games).

- [LawCraft](https://www.icivics.org/games/lawcraft)
- [How a Bill becomes Law](https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Browse/Search:how%20a%20bill%20becomes%20law%20game)
- [There Oughta Be a Law](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16477/there-oughta-be-law)

Please note that it might be worth asking in [Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com) if asking for help developing an actual game is on-topic. I don't know that anyone's ever done it before. We've had questions about developing the basics of sports in the context of a developing world... but this one's kinda new!

Also, a pen-and-paper game about law is pretty complex. The purpose of law is to balance personal freedoms/rights against social/societal needs. The bulk of U.S. (and most country's) laws exist because of decades, centuries, and millennia of lawsuits and events that caused someone to think, "there should be a law about that...". Somehow your game would need to bring those events into play, along with simplifications of the infinite variety of interpersonal reactions. It would be fun to develop... but my head aches thinking about it!

### Edit

I completely lost the idea that Meph was looking to simulate *courtrooms.* Games like that also exist.

- [Court Quest](https://www.icivics.org/games/court-quest)
- [Ghost Court](https://bullypulpitgames.com/games/ghost-court/)
- [Judged: A Court Simulator](https://store.steampowered.com/app/384880/Judged_A_Court_Simulator/)

This kind of context could, IMO, be readily converted to a pen-and-paper or a card game (A hybrid would make more sense, I think). But it requires someone to create the context of the game (or use cards to do this). The crime or reason to sue, the witnesses and facts of the case.

Frankly, it might lend best to an RPG with a DM who's either creating their own modules or using commercially-available modules. But the "player handbooks" are mostly the (e.g.) U.S. Code.

As I mentioned in a comment to Meph — heaven help whomever plays a case involving the IRS. That's some of the most voluminous and intertwined law on the planet.

Comment: Say, if the United States was to be destro- wouldn't be able to modify their laws anymore for some reason, and the games were based on a static set that was then purged of nonsense/WTF? laws (i.e: we actually put those in a diferent book, wanna play with them, gimme 20 bucks), would that be any shorter?

Comment: I would need to know more about what the goals of your game are. If the game is about making laws, that wouldn't help. If the game was only about using laws... that's different. It's something like a simulation of the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission, which would be a business simulation (which is what games are, at their simplest, a simulation). You could simulate farms (and their governing regs/laws), automobiles... I guess I didn't fully understand what it is you're trying to achieve with your game?

Comment: Well, I'm not saying players can't make house rules or homebrew content, but they're mostly going to be playing as defense and prosecution lawyers.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense (and I re-read your question, sorry for not fully understanding this). What you're doing is simulating *courtrooms.* The game isn't about making laws, but using laws and establishing precedent. You probably could do that with a combination pen-and-paper/card game. Heaven help anyone playing a version of the game that involves suing/getting-sued-by the IRS.

Comment: And I know exactly what to do with the dice: "roll 1d20 at -3 (because your defendant looks like a humanoid trashbag) to see if the jury agrees with you."